# How do I get an emoticon for the chat?

Tags: steam

It's part of the steam badge and I don't have one in my inventory to use. I know you can buy one, but how do I get one otherwise?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can trade for them, buy them from the [Steam Marketplace](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=753), or they drop when you craft a new badge.  The emoticon will be from the set that is related to the game/event that the badge is for.

To craft a new badge, you need a set of trading cards for a particular game or event.  These can be bought at the Steam Marketplace (same as the emoticons), earned from playing eligible games in your library, or earned during special Steam events.

*Most* emoticons are cheap - cheaper than buying cards for a given game.  Thus, if you are interested in a particular emoticon for which you don't own the game or have a card set, you might start with the Marketplace first.

Answer (score 3):

I got each of mine by crafting badges.

From the [Steam wiki](http://steamtradingcards.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Emoticons):

> Emoticons are little symbols or pictures given to a user once they have crafted a badge.